# maven-guava: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;JJ)V

Tags: maven, apache-spark, guava

I'm experiencing problem with maven (tried sbt as well, same result) and [Google's guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava), which I'm new to.
I found a lot of questions of this kind in SO, but none of the solutions worked for me (searched for internal deps using `mvn tree | less`, excluded guava from everywhere, deleted my local .m2, reset cache in IntelliJ, tried all af the Guava versions starting from 22.0). no matter what, I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.<init>(FileStreamSink.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSink(DataSource.scala:320)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.createV1Sink(DataStreamWriter.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:269)
        at com.appsflyer.Main$.main(Main.scala:49)
        at com.appsflyer.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;JJ)V
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.cooplock.CooperativeLockingOptions$Builder.build(CooperativeLockingOptions.java:58)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.cooplock.CooperativeLockingOptions.<clinit>(CooperativeLockingOptions.java:31)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.<clinit>(GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.java:392)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:235)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:58)
        ... 30 more
```

Here is my pom.xml (some things are commented out to show what I've tried):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-scala-12-maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <spark.version>3.0.1</spark.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.version>2.12.11</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.7.7</hadoop.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
            <scope>${third.party.scope}</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/gcs-connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
            <version>hadoop3-2.1.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.30.10</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>4.4.13</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->


    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repo</id>
            <name>Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        
        <repository>
            <id>apache-repo</id>
            <name>Apache release repo</name>
            <url>https://github.com/adatao/mvnrepos/tree/master/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        
    </repositories>
    

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>com.google.code.sbt-compiler-maven-plugin</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>sbt-compiler-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>1.0.0</version>-->
<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <id>default-sbt-compile</id>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>compile</goal>-->
<!--                            <goal>testCompile</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-scala</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile-scala</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
<!--                    <scalaVersion>${scala.binary.version}</scalaVersion>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>1.6.0</version>-->
<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>exec</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <executable>java</executable>-->
<!--                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>-->
<!--                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>-->
<!--                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>-->
<!--                    <mainClass>testConf</mainClass>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->

            <plugin>
                <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is
                     org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.
                 -->
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

P.S. the goal is to write spark dataframe into GCS.
P.S.S. I see `spark-core_2.12/3.0.1` includes hadoop2.7.4 inside and depends on `guava-14.0.1`, is there any way to use a newer guava (I have exclusions of guava from spark-core, but it does not help)?
Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope.

Comment: Just a guess. Are you using Hadoop 2 or 3? 
The properties show version 2.7 - <hadoop.version>2.7.7</hadoop.version>
but gcs-connector is compiled with 3 -- hadoop3-2.1.6

Comment: nice catch! just modified `hadoop.version` to `3.2.1`, didn't help :(

Comment: I would suggest using hadoop2-2.1.6 of the gcs-connector, since spark 3 is published with Hadoop 2.7, see this topic- http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Use-Hadoop-3-2-as-a-default-Hadoop-profile-in-3-0-0-td28198.html It's a bit old but still relevant afaik.

I would also not exclude guava from the classpath since gcs-connector uses it and it must be present. 2.1.6 published with guava 30.0-jre,.
As the next step I would try to downgrade the connector version because they rely on older guava versions.

Comment: @Gelerion are you talking about [hadoop-common](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common)? there is no 2.1.6 version for it. I've chosen 3.2.1 since Google [claim](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/manage-spark-dependencies) the dep issue was resolved for Hadoop versions above 3

Comment: @Gelerion oh, I got you know, you were talking about the connector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution was to place `guava` to the very beginning of the `<dependencies>`, remove `hadoop` as an independent dependency, switch to hadoop2 (instead of 3) and Java8 (instead of 11) and add `maven-shade-plugin`. the resulting pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-scala-12-maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <spark.version>3.0.1</spark.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.version>2.12.11</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/gcs-connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
            <version>hadoop3-2.1.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- conflicts with Spark dependencies -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!-- conflicts with Spark dependencies -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.113.6</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repo</id>
            <name>Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-repo</id>
            <name>Apache release repo</name>
            <url>https://github.com/adatao/mvnrepos/tree/master/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-scala</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile-scala</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
<!--                    <scalaVersion>${scala.binary.version}</scalaVersion>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>com.google.**:*</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <!-- Register a provider with the shaded name instead-->
                                        <exclude>META-INF/services/org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com.google.*:*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                                    <exclude>slf4j</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.hadoop</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.curator</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.spark</exclude>
                                    <exclude>javax.activation</exclude>
                                    <exclude>javax.annotation</exclude>
                                    <exclude>javax.inject</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.commons</exclude>
                                    <exclude>javax.servlet</exclude>
                                    <exclude>javax.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>io.netty</exclude>
                                    <exclude>io.dropwizard.metrics</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.twitter</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.joda</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>com.shaded.google</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is
                     org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.
                 -->
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```